# What is the deduced type of a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int& k) { std::cout << "int&\n"; }
void foo(int&& k) { std::cout << "int&&\n"; }
void foo(const int& k) { std::cout << "const int&\n"; }
void foo(const int&& k) { std::cout << "const int&&\n"; }    
int main() {
  static  constexpr int k = 1;
  foo(k);
  foo(1);
}
```

The output is:

```
const int&
int&&
```

What exactly is a constexpr variable treated as?
The overload for `foo` gives `const int&`.

Edit: Moving on with constexpr being deduced as `const T&`;

**Why does a constexpr at class scope fail to be passed to a function taking universal reference?!**

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void goo(T&& k) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(k), const int&>::value, "k is const int&");
}

class F {
  static  constexpr int k = 1;
public:
  void kk2 () { goo(k); }
};

int main () {
  F a;
  a.kk2();
}
```

The above fails to compile giving error `undefined reference to F::k`
However the below passes:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void goo(T&& k) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(k), const int&>::value, "k is const int&");
}

int main() {
  static  constexpr int k = 1;
  goo(k);
}
```

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I think that sentence is referring to `goo(T&& k)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `N3337 [dcl.constexpr]/9:` A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. [...]

Since you declared `k` as `constexpr`, it is also declared as `const`, so the `const int&` is selected in overload resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo(1);
```

In this case a temporary variable with the value `1` is passed to the function `foo`, hence non-const rvalue.

```
/*static*/ constexpr int k = 1;
foo(k);
```

Here a named const variable with the value `1` is passed to the function `foo`, hence const lvalue. The `static` keyword has no effect on a `constexpr` variable at function scope.

> What exactly is a constexpr variable treated as?

When used in an expression that is not a constant expression, a `constexpr` variable is just a `const` variable.

> Why does a constexpr at class scope fail to be passed to a function taking universal reference?!

You are getting a linker error because you odr-used the variable without defining it. You need a definition of `F::k` at namespace scope in exactly one translation unit, just like you did for `static const` member variables in C++98.